# Print file from the beginning until a pattern is found in the 3rd column

Tags: awk, sed

At the end of the third column there are three numbers that start with `1.0`, how can I print all rows from the beginning until the first of these three numbers (it is in bold below) is found? is there a simple, one-liner solution with awk or sed?

```
-80.2743682     -8.6420053      0
-80.2740679     -8.6418526      0.0371169854015
-80.2737584     -8.641709       0.0747022394455
-80.2734489     -8.6415562      0.112728651431
-80.2731395     -8.6414126      0.150303954286
-80.27283       -8.6412689      0.187893918808
-80.2725297     -8.6411162      0.22501096103
-80.2722202     -8.6409635      0.263032506523
-80.2719108     -8.6408198      0.300612533441
-80.2716103     -8.6406581      0.33821233839
-80.27131       -8.6405053      0.375334461391
-80.2710095     -8.6403526      0.412471166086
-80.2707001     -8.6401999      0.450482911927
-80.2703906     -8.6400471      0.488509444666
-80.2700993     -8.6398853      0.52522713763
-80.2697989     -8.6397326      0.562354088058
-80.2694894     -8.6395709      0.600828217536
-80.2691981     -8.6394181      0.637071247595
-80.2688886     -8.6392473      0.676023425931
-80.2685882     -8.6390946      0.713150425596
-80.2682788     -8.6389509      0.750730603804
-80.2679783     -8.6387981      0.787872459485
-80.2676599     -8.6386635      0.825947927083
-80.2673686     -8.6385108      0.862185868818
-80.2670501     -8.6383762      0.900271491364
-80.2667406     -8.6382235      0.938293256103
-80.2664311     -8.6380798      0.975883478883
-80.2661217     -8.6379452      **1.01304928976**  <--- print until here
-80.2658214     -8.6378015      1.04972439283
-80.2655029     -8.6376578      1.08821462134
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please can you make the question explicit regarding whether the first line with >1 should or should not be included in the output.

Comment: @alaniwi *until* implies the first line with >=1 is excluded

Comment: @oguzismail I agree that that is probably the interpretation, but there is no harm in being explicit in order to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk it'd be:

```
awk '$3>=1{exit} 1' file
```

Comment: I've asked for clarification of the question, regarding whether the final line should be included in the output or not. In this answer, it would not be included. This could be modified to `awk '$3>=1{print ; exit} 1' file` if it is required.

Comment: @alaniwi In that case `awk '1; $3>=1{exit}' file` would be more idiomatic

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples only.

```
awk '1;$NF~/^1\.0/{exit}' Input_file
```

Also in case your Input_file is having more than 3 fields then change above to:

```
awk '1;$3~/^1\.0/{exit}' Input_file
```

---

---

Sorry I am little confuse with description in case you need to print till 3rd occurrence of `1.0` then try following(though your shown bold lines shw you want to print till very first occurrence only but adding this in case anyone needs it).

```
awk '1;$NF~/^1\.0/ && ++count==3{exit}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r '1,/.+ +.*+ +0.263/ p' -n < Input_file
```

this sed says:

- don't print anything from `Input_file`
- except for, starting with line 1
- up to the line matching `/.+ +.*+ +0.263/`. Which means:

  - 1 or more characters followed by
  - 1 or more spaces followed by
  - 1 or more characters followed by
  - 1 or more spaces followed by
  - the number 0.263
- print these lines

The regex can definitely be improved, by specifying start of line and spaces vs tabs. But the general idea is there.

Comment: `-r` is not really portable while its equivalent `-E` is widely implemented